# How to markup wordpress site using Schema.org?

Tags: plugins, seo, html

Since using the markup format from Schema.org is something that is important for a website from an SEO perspective: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/14

> ...
>
> - Mark up your site using schema.org, if applicable, to display rich snippets.
>
> ...

Then what exactly is the best or just rather more efficient and effective ways of having Schema.org markup for every single eligible item on the website?

Are there WordPress plugins that can help facilitate this, like some of the SEO ones or what have you?

Answer (score 0):

As anything related to the structure of the generated HTML this is a pure theme issue. There s unlikely to be any relevant plugin as you need to know the content in order to produce the relevant html markup. You might be able to find plugins to do some specific schema.org markup but that standard is very big and I doubt you will find a plugin or even a set of them that will cover everything.

Comment: I disagree with you. Schemas data can be insered using `<meta>` tags, which doesn't require any specific HTML markup in themes. And, even better, you can use [json-ld format](http://json-ld.org/), [the new recommended format for structured data from Google](https://developers.google.com/schemas/formats/json-ld); it doesn't requiere any theme related code neither. In fact, I use json-ld through a plugin in several sites. I agree with you with the concern about if a plugin already exists in WordPress.org repository; it is unlikely a plugin with support for all schemas data types exists.

Comment: first time that I see the json-ld format, so yes it might actually be done without changing the HTML of the content. You might have an event plugin that does the event schema and then you need to use plugin for the event itself as well. My experience till now is that themes seems to be a more natural place for it especially if you want to handle this after you already have a live site.

Comment: Again, I disagree with you. From my point of view, a theme isnot the more natural place where Schemas should be defined. Actually, WordPress themes is for presentation of the data in a HTML document with a specific look and feel; Schemas defines the data type and its deatils and shouldn't interact with the presentation/look and feel of the data; it is the same no matter the them you are using. Even more, it should be valid for any document type, not only HTML documents. That is why (I think) Schemas is moving away from HTML and also Google recomendations about Schemas.

Comment: So, actually a plugin is the most natural place to include Schemas because it doesn't depend on look and feel. You can change the theme and totally change the look and feel of your site; the data type and its details remain the same. So plugin is the correct place for Schemas.